# Бесконечный прогресс бар при загрузке сайта

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, progress-bar, загрузка

При открытии сайта https://top-masters.com/ наблюдается бесконечная загрузка сайта. Сайт работает на Wordpress. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: у вас полно вывозов jquery до подключения библиотеки, стоит отключить autoptimaze и проверить работу сайта без него

Comment: а как отключить autoptimaze. Вернее где его можно отключить?

Comment: ВЫ ЛУЧШИЙ! В КОНСОЛЕ ВОРДПРЕСС, ГДЕ ВСЕ ПЛАГИНЫ НАДО ДЕАКТИВИРОВАТЬ ПЛАГИН AUTOPTIMAZE! СПАСИБО!